# How do computers handle numbers greater than the size of int

Tags: int, size

I understand there are long and unsigned longs available, but if I were to do computations on astronomical numbers, how do computers handle those?

I guess if I were working with C, then in that case the size of int is really dependent on the platform, but even in that case the size can not be 64 bit right?

For java I guess the size is limited, how do they do it then?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

> In computer science, arbitrary-precision arithmetic, also called
>   bignum arithmetic, multiple precision arithmetic, or sometimes
>   infinite-precision arithmetic, indicates that calculations are
>   performed on numbers whose digits of precision are limited only by the
>   available memory of the host system. This contrasts with the faster
>   fixed-precision arithmetic found in most arithmetic logic unit (ALU)
>   hardware, which typically offers between 8 and 64 bits of precision.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: So basically, we give up the notion of int being of a specific length and use whatever is available in memory to write data, and then write programming languages to work with them.
It must be at a hardware level that we have Arbitrary precision arithmetic taken care of, like we have a ALU in hardware right?

Comment: Basically, what is am asking apparently is that if I were to do Arbitrary precision arithmetic on my personal computer, using the libraries that are available out there, I will not be able to do it since there is more to just libraries isnt it? Is there hardware support required for it?